React-Tabulator v0.12.7: TypeError: Tabulator is not a constructor
I was working on a proof of concept using React-Tabulator (specifically v0.12.7) for an existing React project.
I had created React (v17.0.2) using create-react-app.
Here is the Package.json:
{
  "name": "table-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-tabulator": "0.12.7",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}

App.js looks like this with React-Tabulator
import 'react-tabulator/lib/styles.css'; // required styles
import 'react-tabulator/lib/css/tabulator.min.css'; // theme
import { ReactTabulator } from 'react-tabulator';

function App() {
  const data = Array(200).fill({
    id: 1,
    name: 'Bob',
    col: 'red',
  })
  
  const columns = [
    { title: 'Name', field: 'name', width: 150 },
    { title: 'Favourite Color', field: 'col' },
  ]

  return (
    <ReactTabulator
      data={data}
      columns={columns}
      options={{ movableColumns: true, movableRows: true }}
    />
  );
}

export default App;

Problem is when I run this project, I get below error on chrome console
ReactTabulator.js:111 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Tabulator is not a constructor
    at default_1.<anonymous> (ReactTabulator.js:111:1)
    at step (ReactTabulator.js:57:1)
    at Object.next (ReactTabulator.js:38:1)
    at fulfilled (ReactTabulator.js:29:1)

However, If I upgrade the package of React-Tabulator to latest version (v0.19.0), it works fine.
Any clues on how to fix this issue?
